# Oracle query: compare values in table to other values in same table

Tags: sql, oracle

We have an Oracle based system that manages devices and stores their details and configuration in a table called "configs". Each device is made up of several modules and the configuration of each module is saved as a comma-separated string. For example:

```
device_id   module  values
1           1       3,4,2,3
1           2       4,1,3,4
1           3       2,1,2,3
1           4       6,4,2,1
1           5       1,4,2,3
1           6       1,3,4,4
2           1       3,4,2,3
2           2       4,1,3,4
2           3       2,3,2,3
2           4       6,4,2,1
2           5       1,8,2,3
2           6       1,3,4,4
3           1       3,4,2,3
3           2       4,1,3,4
3           3       2,1,2,3
3           4       6,4,2,1
3           5       1,4,2,3
3           6       1,3,4,4
4           1       3,4,2,3
4           2       4,1,3,4
4           3       2,1,2,4
4           4       6,4,2,1
4           5       1,4,2,3
4           6       1,3,7,4
```

I need to audit the system and identify each module whose configuration does not match a known good config. Ideally, I want to run a query like this, assuming the config for device 1 is my good config:

```
select device_id,module 
from configs 
where values != (select values from configs where device_id = 1)
```

But that returns an error:

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

If I change the query to this, it works:

```
 select device_id,module 
 from configs 
 where values = (select values from configs where device_id = 1 and module = 1);
```

But then I have to run the query for each value of "module".

What I'd like to do is write a query that will allow me to do this in one go. It's been hinted that I could use a cursor statement but I've struggled to find an "oracle cursors for dummies" type article and nothing I've looked at has helped me so far, including http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions006.htm#SQLRF52057. Can anyone suggest something?

Thanks.

Comment: how do you determine what "a known good config" is?

Comment: Basically, all of the configs should be the same, but over time things have been tinkered with. We know the config of device 1 is what all the others should be.

Answer (score 0):

Does the module numbers have to match ? i.e. is the configuration of the module 2 (of the device 1) considered as a good configuration for the module 3 (of some other device)

If so, there are several good configuration (that's why the db says `single-row subquery returns more than one row`). You have to account for that :

```
select device_id, module 
from configs 
where values not in (select values from configs where device_id = 1)
```

If not, you have to choose the one matching the considered row, for example :

```
select device_id, module
from configs c1
where values = ( 
    select values
    from configs c2 
    where device_id = 1 
    and c1.module = c2.module
)
```

Comment: The entire config of device 1 (that is, all modules) should be how all the other devices are configured.

Comment: So, the second query is probably better as it compares each module of each device with the same module of the device 1

Comment: Thanks. Both your suggestions return a set of results, but each is a different set so I need to pick over them to work out which one is right.

Answer (score 0):

Your query that is producing errors is attempting to compare a list of items in a single value context. You need to change your "!=" to "not in" and it should work. Here is the adjusted query:

```
select device_id, module 
from configs 
where values not in (select values from configs where device_id = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, I suppose you can use something like this:

```
DECLARE
    device_string VARCHAR2 (100);
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM configs WHERE device_id = 1)
    LOOP
        SELECT listagg(device_id, ';')
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY device_id)
        INTO device_string
        FROM configs
        WHERE values != i.values AND module=i.module;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
            ' Bad config for module ' || i.module ||
            ' in devices: ' || device_string);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Forgive my stupidity, but this doesn't execute when I hit enter at the end, I just get another prompt. I've tried putting it into a text file and executing it with @ but get the same thing.

Comment: >" I just get another prompt"
Are you using **sqlplus** ?
If so, i think you need to add `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;` before the `DECALRE` statement and after last `END;` add slash '/'